# SweetAlert2 does not work properly as I expect

Tags: sweetalert2

It may be a dumb question, but I just cannot figure out why sometimes Swal.fire works and sometimes it doesn't.

The alert I am using is quite simple -

```
Swal.fire({
            title:'Slow response!',
            text:'Please indicate the side as quickly and accurately as possible',
            icon:'warning'

          })
```

But it only works when within a function starts as:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {...})
```

Since this function is built in a constructor, I add .bind(this) at the end to make use of "this" object. Nevertheless, my sweetalert does not work in this situation. It also does not work if the inner function starts as:

```
$(document).keydown((e)=> {...})
```

I did not see any errors in console. Any comments are highly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using arrow functions then?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Only arrow function or adding .bind(this) in the end makes the other unmentioned inner functions work.